# How to aggregate a combination of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have status as won and stage as won so am not sure how to group that

I want to have 5 groups

1. Prospect and status is open as Prospect stage
2. Qualify and status is open as Qualify stage
3. Develop and status is open  as Develop stage
4. Solution and status is open  as Solution stage
5. Proof and status is open  as Proof stage
6. Close and status is open as Close stage
7. **status is won and stage=prospect,qualify,develop,solution,proof,close,won**

Table 1

```
owneridname custom_totalamount  custom_phasename    statecodename
ABC         900                 Prospect - 0%       Won
ABC         800                 Qualify - 10%       Won
ABC         700                 Develop - 20%       Won
ABC         600                 Solution - 40%      Won
ABC         500                 Proof - 60%         Won
ABC         400                 Close - 80%         Won
ABC         300                 Won - 100%          Won
ABC         100                 Prospect - 0%       open
ABC         200                 Prospect - 0%       open
ABC         400                 Qualify - 10%       open
ABC         200                 Qualify - 10%       open
ABC         300                 Develop - 20%       open
ABC         500                 Solution - 40%      open
ABC         700                 Proof - 60%         open
ABC         800                 Close - 80%         open
```

Expected Result

```
owneridname custom_totalamount  custom_phasename 
ABC         300                 Prospect - 0% 
ABC         600                 Qualify - 10% 
ABC         300                 Develop - 20% 
ABC         500                 Solution - 40% 
ABC         700                 Proof - 60% 
ABC         800                 Close - 80% 
ABC         4200                Won - 100%
```

The last 4200 row am not sure how to generate that

```
SELECT 
owneridname,sum(custom_totalamount),custom_phasename
  FROM table1
  group by owneridname,custom_phasename
```

Comment: How your expected result have `Prospect 0% = 300` but your data doesnt? The last row shouldnt be `Won 100 % = 3200`?

Comment: @gurwinder I see Gordon answer the other question and if he didn't close this question dont know why would you close it. Also In the other question there was a separation `GROUP BY`  for each `OPEN` elements, but a Total for the `WON` In this case there is detail and total but only for the `WON` rows

Comment: @juan My data isnt well represented in the data base, there is won as stage and won as status, so if something is won in prospect it should go to Won group not be in prospect group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add this by using an UNION ALL statement.

```
SELECT owneridname, sum(custom_totalamount), custom_phasename
FROM @t
WHERE statecodename = 'open'
GROUP BY owneridname, custom_phasename
UNION ALL
SELECT owneridname, sum(custom_totalamount), 'Won - 100%'
FROM @t
WHERE statecodename = 'won'
GROUP BY owneridname
```